# insert image's path and retrieve it from SQLite

Tags: android

can anyone give me a method to how save a image's path in database and how to display the image in imageView.

Comment: Search engines are your friend.  Have you considered, perhaps, googling "ImageView tutorial" or "Android SQLite example?"

Answer (score 0):

You can store images and show into **imageview** this way.

```
String  path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/Directoryname";
String imageName;
File mFolder = new File();
                if (!mFolder.exists()) {
                    mFolder.mkdir(path);
                }
                  imageName= "yourimagename.jpg";
                //now you can store imagepath into database and imageto your sdcard so we can show image as per our requirement
                File file = new File (mFolder, imageName);
                if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
                Bitmap thumbnail = you can convert your image to bitmap and store into database.
                try {
                       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                       thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                       out.flush();
                       out.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                //it will be store in your sdcard.

                //for displaying image into imageview
                File f = new File(path+"/"+imageName);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), options);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

If you are finding any trouble then let me know.